# Sprintf buffer Char[] trailing null

Tags: c, sockets, client-server, send, printf

Trying to print out a char[] that holds the buffer  using sprintf on client. The last character is '\0'. This is my server code:

```
char buffer[MAXDATASIZE];
char res[MAXDATASIZE];

memset(buffer, '\0', MAXDATASIZE);
memset(res, '\0', sizeof(res));

if ((numbytes=recv(new_fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0)) == -1) {
        perror("recv");
        exit(true);
}
buffer[numbytes] = '\0'; // add null terminator

sprintf(res, "test \"%s\" not found amongst the batting figures.\n Please check your spelling and try again.", buffer);

if (send(new_fd, res, sizeof(res), 0) == -1){
        perror("send");
}
```

This prints out: test "term" and then doesn't not print the rest of the res[] (i.e. "not found amongst..."). How do I fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have Undefined Behavior by doing

```
buffer[numbytes] = '\0'
```

As `numbytes=recv(new_fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0)` may be the `sizeof(buffer)`, `buffer[numbytes] = '\0'` writes `buffer[sizeof(buffer)]`.  Use

```
recv(new_fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1, 0)
```

---

Further, `sprintf(res, ...` writes to `res` the value in `buffer`.  Given the extra text in the format, overrun is possible.  Suggest

```
const char format[] = "test \"%s\" not found amongst the batting figures.\n Please check your spelling and try again.";
char res[MAXDATASIZE+sizeof(format)];
sprintf(res, format, buffer);
```

---

Lastly, you may want

```
send(new_fd, res, strlen(res) /* maybe +1 */), 0)
```